# Core processes are started to run under another user, not root

Tags: linux, root, uid

I have added a new user as **abc**, with UID 0 and GUID 0 (as same as root. I know, it was a bad idea)

Now, when I connect to ssh via **root**, it's shown as **abc**@localhost, not **root**@localhost. Also, all core processes are started to run under **abc**, not root.

How can I fix it? Processes must run under root and also, how can I delete this **abc** user?

Comment: `root` ***is*** UID 0. You can call `root` anything you want (which is a valid user name) and it will be just as much `root`. See [my answer to *Does the root account always have UID/GID 0?*](https://superuser.com/a/626845/53590) on [su].

Answer (score 3):

Processes run as  a UID.  The mapping to names like root is just for human convenience.

So when 'ps' looks at the process and sees it running as UID 0, it consults the /etc/passwd file and finds what username matches it.  Depending on how it searches the file it might return root or your new abc user.  But both usernames are really the same account - UID 0.

Deleting the lines for abc in /etc/passwd and /etc/group should fix it.  Be careful though - deleting the wrong lines will do more harm than good.